# nodemon - restart on changes to json files

Tags: node.js

I'm using 'nodemon' to restart node on file changes. However it doesn't seem to trigger when json files have changed. Anyone know if there is a way to set this up?

Also, is there a programmatic way to restart from within the running app itself?
I suppose running it with 'forever' and throwing an error would do it.
Any pointers much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the extensions that it monitors seem to be hardcoded in the script:

https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/nodemon.js#L334

`program.ext = '.coffee|.js';`

You could hack it to make it work for json as well:

`git clone https://github.com/remy/nodemon.git`
`cd nodemon`

Modify that line in `nodemon.js` to `program.ext = '.coffee|.js|.json';`

`npm install -g .` (it should use the cloned git folder instead of the npm registry)

Or you could use my [script](https://github.com/mihaifm/simplemon), although it's less stable than nodemon.

Comment: lovely - thanks for the advice. Also, simplemon looks good thanks

Comment: This answer is out of data (written in 2012), nodemon supports specifying the extension you want to monitor, as per the answer below.

Answer (score 31):

**Marciej's** approach worked for me:

```
nodemon -e js,html
```

You can also configure this in a `nodemon.json` config file. Here's how we're currently using it:

```
{
    "execMap": {
        "js": "node --harmony"
    },
    "script": "server.js",
    "ext": "js html"
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Just use "-e" command line switch

Answer (score 10):

You can specify nodeman configs within package.json file also

```
"nodemonConfig": {
    "ext": "js, ts, graphql, json"
  }
```